# Creating multi dimensional array with a data file in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am in a basic Java class...I know how to make a single array using data from a file and I can make a multi dimensional array that just ends up spitting back the number of integers I input, but I can't figure out how to make a multi dimensional array that uses the data already in the file.

This is the code I have for the array using the data file...

```
 // read the file and put it in an array
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:/Schoolwork/unit7.txt"));
    // create the array
    int [] result = new int [250000];
    int i =0;
    // load the array
    while(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    result[i++] = scanner.nextInt();
```

and this is what I have to create the multi dimensional array (2500x10 for the assignment)
int rows = 2500;
int columns = 100;

```
int[][] array = new int[rows][columns];

int value = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        array[i][j] = value;
        value++;
        }
    }`

System.out.println("The 2D array is: ");
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
        }
    System.out.println();`
```

Which just puts in the integers up to 250,000, but when I try to somehow add the array from the first code it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:/Schoolwork/unit7.txt"));
int[][] array = new int[rows][columns];

for (int i = 0; i < array.length && scanner.hasNextInt(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length && scanner.hasNextInt(); j++) {
        array[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I piecemealed it out and think I understand it...but when I try to input it, it is saying that rows and columns aren't resolved to a variable still?

Comment: Well, "rows" and "columns" were from YOUR CODE, not mine. I assumed you had already declared and initialized them...